# WCF - Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the https endpoint

Tags: .net, wcf, service

When i try to run my service, i get an following error:
"Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding BasicHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [https]."

My service declaration:

```
 <service name="service" behaviorConfiguration="serviceEndpointBehavior">

    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="https://abc:12704/service"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>

    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBinding2" contract="service"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="basicHttpBinding"/>

  </service>
```

Binding:

```
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttpBinding2" maxReceivedMessageSize="1000000">
      <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="1000000" maxStringContentLength="1000000"/>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
```

I have also following declaration in behavior:

```
<behavior name="serviceEndpointBehavior">
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="1000000"/>
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
</behavior>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: are you able to browse `https://abc:12704/service` on any browser?

Comment: Yes I can. My wsdl looks great.

Comment: Try changing the security mode from "`Transport`" to "`none`" in web.config

Comment: Unfortunately still the same ;/

Answer (score 1):

The binding you defined is a basic http binding. Your endpoint is http with added security (https). You need to define a security on your binding, or they won't match. You cannot have https without any security.

You need to find a good tutorial or book on this, because there is more to https than a few entries in the config file. You will need a certificate and you will need a web server that actually does this (hint: Cassini, the inbuild VS webserver will NOT do any https... it will simply drop it without giving any warnings).

Comment: I added security to my basic http binding:

          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>

But still nothing.